Proving two 2-spheres in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ connected by line segment is simply connected.
This space is obtained by identifying the $0$ in the unit interval with the north pole of one sphere, and the point $1$ of the unit interval with the south pole of the other sphere. I am familiar with a corollary in Munkres that states:

Suppose $X = U \cup V$, where $U, V \subset X$ are open; suppose $U \cap V$ is nonempty and path connected. If $U$ and $V$ are simply connected, then $X$ is simply connected.

I have made attempts at finding simply connected $U$ and $V$ but to no avail. I thought of 'pushing' the spheres towards each other to create two spheres that are connected in one point. I know the resulting space is simply connected, but I'm not sure whether this is the right approach. Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

have you tried drawing the situation you described and try to find candidates for open sets $U,V$ in the theorem you stated? It is also helpful to think about homotopy equivalence and the fundamental group.

What's the most symmetric way you could divide $X$ into two open subsets with a small intersection?

@GregMartin Would the most symmetric way be to take $U = S_{1}^{2} \cup (0, 1/2]$ and $V = [1/2, 1) \cup S_{2}^{2}$, where $S_{1}^{2}$ and $S_{2}^{2}$ represent the respective spheres. How can I see that these sets are open and simply connected?

the idea is right, but these sets are not open - try to enlargen your interval parts slightly

Would $U = S_{1}^{2} \cup (0,1)$ and $V = (0,1) \cup S_{2}^{2}$ work? They are open since their complements are the other spheres respectively. I don’t know how to show they are simply connected.

that works - now both of these sets are "spheres with a line glued on", $S^2 \sqcup [0,1)$. What do you know about the fundamental groups of homotopy equivalent spaces? What do you know about the homotopy class of the line?

@Nuffie I know homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic fundamental groups, but I don’t what it would be homotopy equivalent to such that the fundamental group is trivial.

$S^2$ has trivial fundamental group. Can you try to find a homotopy equivalence between $U$ (the sphere with a line glued on) and $S^2$? Your idea of squishing down the interval was the right direction.

further explanation from the comments above:
We want to use the corollary you stated in the question. Pick $U = S_1^2 \sqcup_{p_{-}\mapsto 0} [0,1)$ and $V= S_2^2\sqcup_{p_+\mapsto 1} (0,1]$ where you glue the poles in the same way you described. These are open sets with respect to the quotient topology since their preimage is the union of one sphere with the half-open interval, which is open with respect to the subspace topology of $[0,1]$.
Now the intersection $U\cap V= (0,1)$ is path connected and nonempty. If we can show that $U$ and $V$ have trivial fundamental group, we are done. The symmetry of the situation (more specifically the fact that $U$ and $V$ are homemorphic) allows us to prove it for just one of the subspaces $U$ or $V$.
We know that if two spaces are homotopy equivalent, they have the same fundamental group. The idea is to now contract the line $[0,1)$ glued to the sphere to the single point $\{0\} \sim p_{-}$ which is the south pole on $S_1^2$. This is even stronger than a homotopy equivalence, we actually show that the $S_1^2$ is a deformation retract of $U$.
For this, we just define a map $H\colon U\times [0,1] \to U$ via
$$H(x,t) = \begin{cases} x, & x \in S_1^2 \\ (1-t)x, & x \in [0,1]\end{cases}.$$
Note that $H$ is continuous and the identity map on $S_1^2$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, it leaves this subspace invariant for all $t$. Furthermore, $H(.,0)$ is the identity map on $U$ and $H(.,1)$ maps all points of $U$ to $S_1^2$. This shows that $S_1^2$ and $U$ are homotopy equivalent (even a deformation retract). Since $S_1^2$ has trivial fundamental group, $U$ and $V$ do aswell and your corollary is applicable.
